# How do I select a column that is not used by group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id | gender |  max   
---+--------+--------
 1 | F      |   5972
 1 | M      |   2428
 2 | F      |   1954
 3 | M      |   2093
 3 | F      |   2118
```

I have merge 2 tables to the table above.
I want to find the highest score from the same id

output table should be something like this:

```
id | gender |  max   
---+--------+--------
 1 | F      |   5972
 2 | F      |   1954
 3 | F      |   2118
```

This can be easy if I do not need to print the gender as I can use the max comment and the group by clause.

```
select id, max(max)
group by id
order by id;
```

above will have the same number of rows, but the problem is I cannot print the gender.

Answer (score 2):

This should be smooth:

```
select b.id, b.gender,b.max from (
select dense_rank() over(partition by id order by max desc) as rk,id, gender, max
from table
)
where b.rk = 1
```

-- Adding :
We can additionally add condition like "gender" in the order by in the RANK FUNCTION  if you don't want the multiple gender records in case of a tie of max.

Comment: Why would you use dense rank? (if it's deliberately to return multiple records in the event of a tie, you should fully explain that.)

Comment: if i understand you correctly , then yes dense_rank function should return multiple records in case of a tie , we can add a distinct in the selection statement to get it corrected if required.

Comment: If two records are tied for the highest value in `max`, but have different values in `gender`, then adding `DISTINCT` won't stop two record being returned *(for the same `id`)*.  The OP may *require* that only one record be returned in such cases.  If so, the using `ROW_NUMBER()` will guarantee only one record chosen, though which record is chosen will be arbitrary.  Alternatively, adding additional columns the the `OVER()` clause's `ORDER BY` can mitigate against a tie happening in the first place.  None of this behaviour is explained in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, max desc;
```